# Execute script remotely on AWS VPC private instance

Tags: bash, shell, amazon-vpc

I'm in process of setting up continuous integration and deployment of projects onto AWS EC2 instances within VPC using GoCD (the same can
be tried in Jenkins as well). Ideally I would like to trigger the build, distribute and deploy/restart the projects from my GoCD system.
I'm able to build and distribute project to private instances in VPC. However I'm having issues in restarting the project on the private
instance. My projects are java [dropwizard] based microservice projects.

For restarting following is what I've done till now:

1- Have a restart.sh script on target private instance to stop and restart the project.

```
#!/bin/sh
BASE_DIR=/home/ubuntu/project
PROJECT=my_deployment_test

# Kill the existing API service
echo "Stopping test Server instance"
#sudo pkill -f 'my_deployment_test.jar'

echo "Starting my_deployment_test"
# Start API Services
sudo /usr/bin/java -cp "$BASE_DIR/$PROJECT/lib/*:$BASE_DIR/$PROJECT" -jar $BASE_DIR/$PROJECT/my_deployment_test.jar  server $BASE_DIR/$PROJECT/conf.yml &
```

This script is working fine when run locally within the private instance. It is killing the existing process and starting the project.

2- Have a remoteRestart.sh script in public/NAT instance through which I can trigger the above restart.sh present in the private instance

```
ssh -i private_key.pem user@host /home/ubuntu/project/my_deployment_test/restart
```

If the above script works then I would a task in GoCD to execute remoteRestart.sh present on the public/NAT instance which internally will
restart the project on private.

However i'm facing issues in executing the remoteRestart.sh on the public/NAT instance itself.
In the console I can see output of echo statement. The earlier project process on the private instance is also getting killed but the
project is not starting.

There was an option to use AWS code deploy service using S3 to distribute but I find [for my case] it will be unnecessary to store all the project items on s3 each time I need to deploy.

Where may I be going wrong with the scripts above. And any alternatives?

thanks

Divya Dyuti

Comment: The command might be getting killed before it restars. Perhaps you could try running the restart script as a background (`&`) process?

Comment: Do you mean using ssh -f option to run the restart script as a background process?

Comment: Thanks a lot. This helped, the changes in command I made to execute the  restart script as background process is:                                                            ssh -i private_key.pem user@host "at now -f /home/ubuntu/project/my_deployment_test/restart"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script might be getting killed when the session disconnects. Try running the script as a background (`&`) process or hand it off via `at now`.

Comment: Thanks sir. Yeah, I handed it off via `at now` and that worked in the first go.